# Why are xmm registers being pxor'ed

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64, sse

[image: Assembly Code]

[source/asm on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/365oaa4zf)

In the above code, I can't figure out why `pxor    xmm0, xmm0` takes place.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, just share the link that godbolt example.

Comment: Okay.. I'll keep that in mind. I'm updating it now

Comment: That's there to clear the bits of `xmm0`, but it is a good question as to why that's needed. From what I can tell neither `cvtsi2sd`, `divsd` nor `movsd` cares about the most significant 64 bits, everything else is set by `cvtsi2sd` or `divsd`.

Comment: @Lala5th: It's there to break the false dependency from the short-signed design of `cvtsi2sd` merging into the destination, instead of zero-extending to the full XMM reg.